# ¿Como validar si en mi servidor Solaris tengo instalado JDK y JRE?

Tags: java, oracle, solaris

Estoy actualmente tratando de ubicar si tengo instalado en mi servidor Solaris JDK y JRE, si lanzo el comando java -version el me retorna la versión del JRE pero no la del JDK y estoy seguro que esta instalado.

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Ante la duda: Instala